# RDS server services on Windows 2022 HyperV runs very slow

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2022

I've built a 15 user RDS server for an office business that mostly runs Quickbooks and MS Office applications.

Setup:
PowerEdge R650 - Hypervisor

- CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6338N CPU @ 2.20GHz x 2
- RAM: 1024 GB 16 slots used out of 32 | DDR4 | Multi-bit ECC
- NIC 1: Embedded - Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
- NIC 2: Integrated - Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet - Hypervisor Connected
- NIC 3: Intel(R) Ethernet 25G 2P E810-XXV Adapter - Feeding to VM1
- NIC 4: Intel(R) Ethernet 25G 2P E810-XXV Adapter - Feeding to VM2

Hypervisor - C Drive - Windows 2022 Std on a RAID 1 Drive
Hypervisor - D Drive - RAID 10 512 block size
VM1 - 64GB RAM - 16 CPUs - Domain control - Windows 2022 STD - VHDX on Hypervisor's D drive
VM2 - 512GB RAM - 64 CPUs - RDS Server - Windows 2022 STD - VHDX on Hypervisor's D Drive

Virtual Disk Setup:
Each VM has separate VHDX for OS and Data, but all on the Hypervisor's Drive.
All VHDXs are 2nd gen. Pre-allocated size.

Issue:
Using Quickbooks, Opening PDFs, browsing directory, and etc - All SLOW. More like 3 to 5 minutes for opening QB, 15 to 30 seconds for opening PDFs

QB 2020 Pro Desktop, QB 2021 Pro Desktop is installed
Adobe Acrobat 2020 Pro installed (non-subscription)

Another thing noticed is that when logging into RDS using Domain Admin, the file browsing speeds up, but when logging in with RDS users, it is slow.

Things done:

1. Disabled VMQs
2. Disabled snapshot
3. Disabled Save State when host shuts down
4. Disabled Windows Indexing and archiving
5. Set the performance to max in iDrac, OS
6. Ran OpenManage for Hardware diagnostic anc checked disk parity, no issues reported
7. No file versioning
8. No antivirus, scanning, cacheing running against Hypervisor's D drive where all VHDX resides

This is happening over just 15 users.

Any advise?

Comment: Your VM's look WAY over provisioned to me. Try dialing back the DC to 4 vCPU and 16GB of vRAM. Dial back the RDS VM to 8 vCPU and 32GB of vRAM. What are the underlying disks and controller... SAS, SATA, or SSD?

Comment: What's the performance doing of the Hyper-V host? What's the performance doing of the VMs. What kind of storage? Especially Disk latency is an important metric to monitor

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions.

1. What is the storage type of D: drive on Hypervisor (SAS/SATA/SSD)?
2. Have you configured roaming profile for these users?

Monitor the disk queue length from "Resource monitor" when any user is logging in. It will give you the understanding if the disk is having issues.

You can also run process explorer and ask user to login. Monitor all the processes when the user is logging in.

It should give you the head start to find the problem.